# How to setup the initial value in select control?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I'm trying to setting up a `select` control on a form, but not achieving the expected results. For me, the strangest thing is it working in the previous control, same type.

This is the function involved:

```
class ProofMSPE(CrearEvidencia):
    model = VRL02
    form_class = VRL02Form

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(ProofMSPE, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['miembro'].queryset = self.pipol
        if self.pipol.count() == 1:
            form.fields['miembro'].widget.initial = [self.pipol[0].id]
        form.fields['meta'].initial = self.meta
        form.fields['meta'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
        return form
```

The `meta`'s control is `select` and I got the expected behavior, ie automatically selects an initial value (`form.fields['meta'].initial = self.meta` and inthe next lines, it disabled (`form.fields ['meta']. widget.attrs ['disabled'] = True`). This is the output in the rendered template:

```
<!-- begin meta-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 input-field">
    <select id="id_meta" name="meta" disabled>
      <option value="">---------</option>
      <option value="1" selected="selected">JOCE-1</option>
      <option value="2">VEL-1</option>
      <option value="3">VEL-2</option>
      <option value="4">VEL-3</option>
    </select>
    <label for="id_meta">Evidencia para la meta</label>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end ./meta -->
```

On the other hand, with the `pipol` field I'm unable to get the same result. The difference, by the way, is this field has some logic: I get a filtered list of people with same criteria and the widget is create whit this list (`form.fields['miembro'].queryset = self.pipol`).

So far so good, but if the queryset has only **one** result (`if self.pipol.count () == 1 :`) I want that this one to be used as inital value (`form.fields ['member']. Widget.initial = [self .pipol [0] .id]`), but this is not working.

This is what appears when the template is rendered:

```
<!-- begin pipol-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 input-field">
    <select id="id_miembro" name="miembro">
      <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
      <option value="2">***@***.mx</option>
    </select>
    <label for="id_miembro">Seleccione el usuario</label>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end ./pipol -->
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: create your custom widget for this purpose (inherit from __django.forms.Select__)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the initial value to the `form.field['miembro']` and not the widget, like you did with `form.fields['meta']`.

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
    form = super(ProofMSPE, self).get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['miembro'].queryset = self.pipol
    if self.pipol.count() == 1:
        # this line here
        form.fields['miembro'].initial = self.pipol[0]
    form.fields['meta'].initial = self.meta
    form.fields['meta'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
    return form
```

Select output would be:

```
<select id="id_miembro" name="miembro">
  <option value="">---------</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">***@***.mx</option>
</select>
```